# Create destination path for .deb file

Tags: debian, deb

I have created a debian package according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51003. I am not able to find the installed files, On installing that .deb file. 
Can anyone tell me the default destination path of .deb file and also how to modify the default destination path ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a .deb file, you should first check with "dpkg -c" what's the content (which will also tell you what's the destination path for the files).

For example if your deb file is 'apackage.deb':

> dpkg -c apackage.deb

Once installed, you can check the destination paths with "dpkg -L". For example (assuming the package name is 'apackage'):

> dpkg -L apackage

That will give you a hint (there's a chance that the building process failed and the package is "empty").

Comment: There's also /var/lib/dpkg/info/_packagename_.list which tells you where stuff ended up.  (I suppose this is the information `dpkg -L` uses as well.)

Answer (score 1):

When the files contained in a deb file, the base directory is '/'.  If you want the files to be stored in a different location, that can be specified during install via command line.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I am new in Linux. So, Can you give me an example of specifying location via command line during installation ?